# Checking command-lines parameters with usage.Options

Tags: python, parameters, twisted

I am parsing and checking command-lines parameters with usage.Options.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from twisted.python import usage
import sys

class Options(usage.Options):
    """
       Defines the default input parameters
    """
    optParameters = [
            ["param", "p", 1, "Int Parameter", int],
        ]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    options = Options()
    try:
        options.parseOptions()
    except Exception, e:
        print '%s: %s' % (sys.argv[0], e)
        print '%s: Try --help for usage details.' % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        if options['param'] < 0 or options['param'] > 10: 
            print "param out of the range [0,10]"
            sys.exit(1)
```

I don't know how to check that value of thi input `param` is a number. If a user accidentally inserts a letter he gets this:

> Parameter type enforcement failed: invalid literal for int() with base
>   10: 'd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use optparse?

```
from optparse import OptionParser
options, args = parser.parse_args()

def args():
    parser = OptionParser(usage='usage: %prog [options]', version='%prog 1.0.0')
    parser.add_option(.....)
    return parser
```

## Update:

You can have something like this. Add and replace everything you want:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = self.get_arg()
        self.set_arg(parser)

    def set_arg(self, parser):
        options, args = parser.parse_args()
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            print 'Error: Usage: python %s <options>' % sys.argv[0]
            sys.exit()
        input_file = options.input_file
        flag = options.flag

    def get_arg(self):
        parser = OptionParser(usage='usage: %prog [options]', version='%prog 1.1.0')
        parser.add_option('-i', '--input-file', action='store', type='string', dest='input_file', default=None,
                            help='Input file.')
        parser.add_option('-f', '--flag', action='store_true', dest='flag', default=False,
                            help='A flag in your app')
        return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: How can I reproduce the example above with OptionParser? thanks

Comment: For example `type='string'` must be `type='int'`